# What does simply giving path in shell script means?

Tags: scripts

I'm going through a shell script coded by some old folks working on my current project. At the end of a file, it simple have the folder/file paths like,

```
/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/rm-vhosts
/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/vhosts
/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/apache
```

at the end of file. When these lines are executing, it throws

```
vhost.sh: line 22: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/rm-vhosts: Is a directory
vhost.sh: line 23: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/vhosts: Permission denied
vhost.sh: line 24: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/apache: Is a directory
```

But i don't have any idea on these since i'm almost new to both Ubuntu and Shell script. What would be the reason or purpose for simply having those lines in a shell script? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
vhost.sh: line 22: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/rm-vhosts: Is a directory
```

Shows there is directory named `rm-vhosts` inside `/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin` directory.

```
vhost.sh: line 23: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/vhosts: Permission denied
```

Shows there is file named `vhosts` inside `/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin` directory.

```
vhost.sh: line 24: /home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin/apache: Is a directory
```

Shows there is directory named `apache` inside `/home/udhay-dev/work/udhay/bin` directory.

`vhost.sh` is the script name.`line xx` means the line number in the script which throws the above message.

Comment: What would be the reason for simply having those lines?

Comment: just to say, it's a directory. But there is no use of having these lines on the script.

Comment: My guess is that the developer put those lines there in order to easily copy-and-paste them, but forgot to remove them.

Comment: @Udhay typically that is the result of treating the directory as a command and then attempting to run it. Why did the script try to run a directory as a command is another question, usually that'd be due to a mistake in the script.